# Java - Exception without interrupting program

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

For example i have list, class and methods:

```
List<Client> myClient = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
public class ClientNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public ClientNotFoundException() {
        super("Client not found!");
    }
}
```

```
public class Client {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String cID;
    boolean subscription = false;

    public String getFullName(){
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

My method:

```
public String getClientName(String customerID){
    String nameCustomer = null;

    for( Client myCustomer: myClient ){
        if( myClient.clientID.equals(customerID) ){
            nameCustomer = myCustomer.getFullName();
            break;
        }
    }

    return nameCustomer;
}
```

How can I cause an exception when client is not found. I just need to display the message without stopping the program. Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you *have* to extend `RuntimeException`?

Comment: And also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839) to learn how to compare strings in Java.

Comment: Though your  exception could benefit from more information, like the `customerID` that wasn't found. Also see [How Do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/). @stdunbar I'd say this is a runtime exception (similar to `NoSuchElementEx`). I personally would not expect clients to not have names as typical behavior, nor is it out of the developer's control.

Comment: Looks like you could use a tutorial about exceptions.  Here is the beginning of Oracle's tutorial about that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html . Or you can Google for others: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+exception+throw+try+catch&oq=java+exception+throw+try+catch

Comment: did you try to catch the exception?

Comment: off-topic: If you don't think you are ready to deal with exceptions, consider some alternatives:  Consider a method that searches `MyClient` for a matching `customerID`.  If a match is found, it returns an `int` index value in `MyClient`. If a match is not found, it returns `-1`. Other alternatives: Return `null` or an empty String (i.e., "") if a match is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, I think the purpose of your method is somewhat pointless. That's because getting a client's name is already served by a different class's method: `Client#getFullName`. You can definitely have a method which returns the `Client` though:

```
public Client getClient(String customerID) {
    for (Client myCustomer : myClient) {
        if (myClient.clientID.equals(customerID)) {
            return myCustomer;
        }
    }
    throw new ClientNotFoundException(customerID);
}
```

Note the lack of any introduced variables, `break;`, or `null` values. You will either retrieve a `Client` (presuming the ID is valid), or you will get an exception if the loop couldn't find one. I made one final improvement for the sake of debugging: note the `customerID` that is passed to the exception now:

```
public class ClientNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public ClientNotFoundException(String customerID) {
        super("Client not found for ID: " + customerID);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can rest easy knowing there aren't clients without names (unless `Client` itself allows such shenanigans):

```
String id = /* some client ID */;
String name = getClient(id).getFullName(); //no null returns!
```

Given the nature of your lookup (`O(n)`), you may benefit further from using a `Map<String, Client>` to quickly find the clients (treated as out-of-scope for this answer), or from keeping the `Client` in a variable between multiple invocations:

```
//PROBLEM: We do the lookup in #getClient every time!
String name = getClient(id).getFullName();
name = getClient(id).getFullName();
//SOLUTION: Only perform a lookup once, if you can help it.
Client c = getClient(id);
String name = c.getFullName();
name = c.getFullName();
```

Answer (score -1):

> I just need to display the message without stopping the program.

You could utilize the *[standard-error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)* stream.

```java
String getClientName(String customerID) {
    for (Client c : myClient)
        if (c.cID.equals(customerID)) return c.getFullName();
    System.err.printf("'%s' not found%n", customerID);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: For future readers: I think the `%n` in the `printf` here should be a `\n`, as it looks like a control character was the intention, not an interpolated value.

Comment: @halfer in Java `%n` [is the platform-specific line separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). The oracle docs specifically encourage using it over `\n` because of its portability across platforms—[\[y\]ou should always use %n, rather than \n.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: Most programs aren’t run at the console: they have GUIs or Web interfaces.